# Read .sql files to disk with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

is there any way to read file names stored in a folder on the disk and filtering through the extension?
This could do with sql server, but now I need to do it with postgresql.
I await your suggestions. Thank you.

This used with sql server:

```
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'dir /b "C:\Folder_Scripts\*.sql"'
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `psql`?

Comment: Please clarify what you want. Is the file an SQL script you want to execute? Is the file on the client machine or on the server machine? In which programming environment or with which client program do you want to accomplish the task.

Comment: No, what I try to do is from Postgresql with pl / sql, to be able to read script files .sql, where with the name of the first script must compare it with the function in the database, if the name exists it should rename it and then execute it, But it exists in the database simply should execute it.
If I need to run it from a client machine. @Laurenz Albe

Answer (score 0):

Your description and comment are none too clear, but I gather that you want to rename SQL script files on disk, open them and execute the contained SQL statements from inside a PL/pgSQL function.

This is not what PL/pgSQL is good at, but here are the tools that you would need:

- There are the standard [SQL functions for reading files](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE-TABLE), which require superuser rights, so you'll need a function owned by a superuser that runs with `SECURITY DEFINER`.
- There are [SQL functions to write files](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/adminpack.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMINPACK-TABLE) in the `adminpack` contrib module, also requiring superuser rights.
- You can execute a string containing an SQL command (or several SQL commands, separated by semicolon) with the [`EXECUTE` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).
- You can find the functions defined in the database in the SQL standard view [`information_schema.routines`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-routines.html).

If you need to do a lot of string processing, you may find PL/pgSQL somewhat clumsy. In that case, consider using [PL/Perl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl.html).

Comment: It happens that when the version is updated, often more than 50 Store Procedure, it is very long the process of doing it manually. The idea is to generate a backup in case it exists and if not directly run it. I'm not understanding your suggestion :(

Comment: Well, I don't understand your question. Let's give it up; we tried.